# Why are my font files not getting downloaded not loaded?

Tags: css, http, flask, font-face

I am working on a webfonts server and I got the api to spit out the css with the correct mime types.They are also getting linked to the page.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pagul';
    src: url('http://localhost:5000/api/webfonts/static/Pagul.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('http://localhost:5000/api/webfonts/static/Pagul.woff')   format('woff'),
         url('http://localhost:5000/api/webfonts/static/Pagul.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The ttf,eot files can be downloaded manualy using the links, for some reason these fonts are
not loaded by the browser what am I doing wrong here ? The font files dont have proper mimetypes is that the issue ?

I tried font-squirells syntax also,it's not working.
PS: The Css is dynamically generated and added to the head ?

Comment: `localhost` ? Is there any console error in Developer Console ?

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths instead of absolutes. For example, if your CSS is in site/css/style.css and your fonts are in the site/api/webfonts/static/ directory:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Pagul;
  src: url('../api/webfonts/static/Pagul.eot');
  src: url('../api/webfonts/static/Pagul.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../api/webfonts/static/Pagul.ttf') format('truetype'),
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Alternatively, use a service like Google Fonts and either link their CSS on your HTML or import it directly into your CSS

Comment: can't do that I am trying to make something like google fonts,so no relative paths.

Comment: Ah sorry, in which case I misunderstood your question